# Typescript "exported external package typings is not a module"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create my first Typescript definition file. The subject code is [filename.js](https://github.com/66pix/filename.js/blob/master/index.js) (index.js):

```
module.exports = {
  extension: extension,
  basename: basename,
  removeSuffix: removeSuffix,
  removeSuffixWithDelimiter: removeSuffixWithDelimiter,
  appendSuffix: appendSuffix,
  appendSuffixWithDelimiter: appendSuffixWithDelimiter,
  directoryName: directoryName
}
function extension(filename) {}
function basename(filename) {}
function removeSuffix(filename) {}
function removeSuffixWithDelimiter(delimiter, filename) {}
function appendSuffix(suffix, filename) {}
function appendSuffixWithDelimiter(suffix, delimiter, filename) {}
function directoryName(filename) {}
```

The definition (index.d.ts) file I have so far:

```
declare module "filename.js" {
  export function extension(filename: string): string;
  export function basename(filename: string): string;
  export function removeSuffix(filename: string): string;
  export function removeSuffixWithDelimiter(delimiter: string|number, filename: string): string;
  export function appendSuffix(suffix: string, filename: string): string;
  export function appendSuffixWithDelimiter(suffix: string, delimiter: string|number, filename: string): string;
  export function directoryName(filename: string): string;
}
```

This works well enough (auto complete works in my editor), but I get a compile error:

> index.ts(21,29): error TS2656: Exported external package typings file 'filename.js/index.d.ts' is not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package definition.

What does this error mean (new to Typescript), and more importantly, how should I modify my definition to make it more correct?

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @emzero no I haven't been able to so far

Comment: Hopefully it will be fixed in TS 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Definition file for the data provided by you can be:-

```
declare module customTypings{
 interface filename{
  extension(filename: string): string;
  basename(filename: string): string;
  removeSuffix(filename: string): string;
  removeSuffixWithDelimiter(delimiter: string|number, filename: string): string;
  appendSuffix(suffix: string, filename: string): string;
  appendSuffixWithDelimiter(suffix: string, delimiter: string|number, filename: string): string;
  directoryName(filename: string): string;
 }
}
```

You can use this typing file by specifying:-

```
/// <reference path="pathName" />
```

See if it works.

For more info refer already created .d.ts files. e.g. [angular-material.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-material/angular-material.d.ts)

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. Also your example doesn't provide accurate auto-completions.

Comment: did you saw already created .d.ts file. may be we should refer those files when creating our so that we don't include any extra thing inside our code.

Comment: I included my index.d.ts file in the question.